# How can I solve "Either the parameter @objname is ambiguous or the claimed @objtype (COLUMN) is wrong."?

Tags: sql, sql-server

If I try to execute below query:

```
EXEC sp_rename 'ENG_TEst.[ENG_Test_A/C_TYPE]', 'ENG_Test_AC_TYPE', 'COLUMN'
```

I get an error:

> Either the parameter@objname is
>   ambiguous or the claimed @objtype
>   (COLUMN) is wrong.

How can I solve it?

Comment: Show us the definition of `ENG_MYTALLY`

Comment: In my case, I got this error because the name of the table that I tried to update not existed.

Comment: This is because of name Conflict of Class(Model) names, when auto creates the tables and ...

Comment: Error message may be very misleading, because it is also shown in case the corresponding table or column name doesn't exist. If you try to execute the same sp_rename twice in a row - you'll see this error, because first rename made the referencing column not existing already. It was my case.

Comment: EXEC sp_rename '[dbo].[TableName].[OldColumnName]', 'NewColumnName', 'COLUMN';

Comment: In my case I was getting this error because I already executed the query once and didn't realize i was executing the line twice (in a migration script). Anyway this question is not duplicate, and should accept new answers.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This works

```
EXEC sp_rename 
@objname = 'ENG_TEst."[ENG_Test_A/C_TYPE]"', 
@newname = 'ENG_Test_A/C_TYPE', 
@objtype = 'COLUMN'
```

Comment: I think objectname should be objname

Answer (score 31):

Nuts. I hit this same error weeks ago, and after a lot of wasted time figured out how to make it work--but I've since forgotten it. (Not much help, other than to say yes, it can be done.)

Have you tried different combinations of brackets, or of with and without brackest? e.g.

```
EXEC sp_rename 'ENG_TEst.ENG_Test_A/C_TYPE', 'ENG_Test_AC_TYPE', 'COLUMN';
EXEC sp_rename '[ENG_TEst].[ENG_Test_A/C_TYPE]', 'ENG_Test_AC_TYPE', 'COLUMN';
EXEC sp_rename '[ENG_TEst].[ENG_Test_A/C_TYPE]', '[ENG_Test_AC_TYPE]', 'COLUMN';
EXEC sp_rename '[ENG_TEst].ENG_Test_A/C_TYPE', 'ENG_Test_AC_TYPE', 'COLUMN';
```

If all else fails, there's always

- Create new table (as "xENG_TEst") with proper names
- Copy data over from old table
- Drop old table
- Rename new table to final name

Comment: for me the 2nd option worked

Comment: I got the Op's error just by itself initially. When I ran sp_rename a another time I got the correct error: Object 'BlahColumnID' cannot be renamed because the object participates in enforced dependencies. In my case it was because BlahColumnID participated in a Computed Column function.

Comment: For me I had to put `[dbo].` in front of the second suggested syntax to make: `[dbo].[ENG_TEst].[ENG_Test_A/C_TYPE]`.  My particular issue was with using Entity Framework's RenameColumn() though, which is a wrapper for sp_rename.

Comment: In my case: `EXEC sp_rename 'ENG_TEst."ENG_Test_A/C_TYPE"', 'ENG_Test_AC_TYPE', 'COLUMN'`;

Answer (score 18):

Are you running the query in the correct database? i.e.,

```
Use MyDatabase;
GO
EXEC sp_rename 'ENG_TEst.[ENG_Test_A/C_TYPE]', 'ENG_Test_AC_TYPE', 'COLUMN';
GO
```

Answer (score 11):

I ran into this today and got it to work with:

```
EXECUTE sp_rename N'dbo.table_name.original_field_name', N'new_field_name', 'COLUMN'
```

To get this syntax, I followed Martin Smith's advice above - open up the table in design view, rename the column and then click table designer | generate change script.  This produced the script below which does the renaming in two steps:

```
/* To prevent any potential data loss issues, you should review this script in
   detail before running it outside the context of the database designer.*/
BEGIN TRANSACTION
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
SET ARITHABORT ON
SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF
SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON
COMMIT
BEGIN TRANSACTION
GO
EXECUTE sp_rename N'dbo.table_name.original_field_name', N'Tmp_new_field_name_1', COLUMN' 
GO
EXECUTE sp_rename N'dbo.table_name.Tmp_new_field_name_1', N'new_field_name', 'COLUMN' 
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.table_name SET (LOCK_ESCALATION = TABLE)
GO
COMMIT
```

Comment: Second this and for the case where SSMS doesn't provide a change script i.e. changing an Index; run a SQL profiler trace whilst renaming to see what script it generates.

Comment: Worked for me too

Answer (score 1):

i also had this issue- very annoying and haven't found a satisfactory sql answer myself yet (aside from long-winded ones involving creating temp tables etc.) and i didn't have time to explore it to the conclusion i'd have liked.

In the end just used SQL Server Management Studio to do it by selecting the table, right-clicking on the column and hitting rename. *simples!*

obviously i'd rather know how to do it without a gui but sometimes you've just gotta get sh** done!

Comment: You can click the "Script" icon in the toolbar to see how SSMS does it!

Comment: @MartinSmith Can you get SSMS to script out the action of renaming a column through the Object Explorer? I can't work out how. The only way I can think of is to use SQL Profiler to trace it, but that's heavy.

Comment: @IainElder - you can but you need to open up the table in design view then rename the column then script the change. If you rename the column directly in the tree view then it just does it without giving a chance to script it.

Comment: @MartinSmith Thanks! Find the table, right-click > Design... > rename the column, right-click > Generate Change Script... > A pop-up window appear with a script that makes the change.

Answer (score 1):

Both of the following work ([as discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5330070/problem-with-renaming-a-column-in-sql-server/5330159#5330159)).

```
exec sp_rename 'ENG_TEst.[[ENG_Test_A/C_TYPE]]]' , 
                'ENG_Test_A/C_TYPE', 'COLUMN'


exec sp_rename 'ENG_TEst."[ENG_Test_A/C_TYPE]"' , 
                'ENG_Test_A/C_TYPE', 'COLUMN'
```

Answer (score 1):

I got this error when Updating code first MVC5 database. Dropping (right click, delete) all the tables from my database and removing the migrations from the Migration folder worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I tried every possible solution on this web site and nothing worked for me. I ended up doing in the design mode. Right click on the table name and then click design. Then I changed the name and saved here. Worked simply.

Answer (score -1):

just try to remove the STATISTICS INDEXES linked to this COLUMN.

Best Regards.