# Problem with Renaming a Column in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2005

So I was trying to rename a column in my table from `Conversion_Fee_PerShare` to just `Conversion Fee`.

I looked up online and found the syntax be:

```
sp_RENAME 'TableName.[OldColumnName]', '[NewColumnName]', 'COLUMN'
```

I wrote my query as:

```
sp_RENAME 'dbo.AllocationDetails.[Conversion_Fee_Per_Share]' , '[Conversion_Fee]', 'COLUMN'
```

The column name has now become `[Conversion_Fee]` instead of `Conversion_Fee`

Now if am trying to rename again like this:

```
sp_RENAME 'dbo.AllocationDetails.[Conversion_Fee]' , 'Conversion_Fee', 'COLUMN'
```

It gives me an error saying:

> Msg 15248, Level 11, State 1,
>   Procedure sp_rename, Line 213 Either
>   the parameter @objname is ambiguous or
>   the claimed @objtype (COLUMN) is
>   wrong.

I tried to Alter Table Drop Column AllocationDetails.[Conversion_Fee] it didn't work that way either.

Whats the right syntax?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Never mind I found out:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.AllocationDetails
DROP COLUMN [[Conversion_Fee]]]
```

OR

```
sp_RENAME 'dbo.AllocationDetails.[[Conversion_Fee]]]' , 'Conversion_Fee', 'COLUMN'
```

these will work fine. :)

Using Double Quotes:

```
exec sp_rename 'dbo.AllocationDetails."[Conversion_Fee]"' , 'Conversion_Fee', 'COLUMN'
```

will also work.

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 7):

```
/*Initial Table*/  
CREATE TABLE AllocationDetails
  (
     Conversion_Fee_Per_Share FLOAT
  )

/*Faulty Rename*/  
EXEC sp_rename
  'dbo.AllocationDetails.[Conversion_Fee_Per_Share]',
  '[Conversion_Fee]',
  'COLUMN'

/*Fixed Rename*/  
EXEC sp_rename
  'dbo.AllocationDetails.[[Conversion_Fee]]]',
  'Conversion_Fee',
  'COLUMN'

DROP TABLE AllocationDetails
```

The column name to use in the second `sp_rename` call is that returned by `SELECT QUOTENAME('[Conversion_Fee_Per_Share]')`.

Alternatively and more straight forwardly one can use

```
EXEC sp_rename
  'dbo.AllocationDetails."[Conversion_Fee]"',
  'Conversion_Fee',
  'COLUMN'
```

`QUOTED_IDENTIFIER` is always set to on for that stored procedure so this doesn't rely on you having this on in your session settings.

Comment: @Andriy - I hadn't but have now. `exec sp_rename 'dbo.AllocationDetails."[Conversion_Fee]"' , 'Conversion_Fee', 'COLUMN'` works also.

Answer (score 3):

To fix this:

```
sp_RENAME 'dbo.AllocationDetails.[[Conversion_Fee]]]' , 'Conversion_Fee', 'COLUMN'
```

Answer (score 0):

Run following queries together.

```
USE [DATABASE_NAME];

GO
EXEC sp_rename '[SCHEMA_NAME].[TABLE_NAME].OLD_COLUMN_NAME', 'NEW_COLUMN_NAME', 'COLUMN';
GO
```

It will resolve your problem