# SQL Server - rename columns

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm trying to rename a few columns within a table that's already created:

```
  USE AdventureWorks
  GO

  EXEC sp_RENAME 'registration.StudentID', 'Temp', 'COLUMN';
  GO
```

But I'm getting this error message:

> *Either the parameter @objname is ambiguous or the claimed @objtype (COLUMN) is wrong.*

If I omit 'COLUMN', this error appears:

> *No item by the name of 'registration.StudentID' could be found in the current database 'AdventureWorks', given that @itemtype was
>   input as '(null)'.*

I'm pretty sure that the `StudentID` column exists and has data in there. Can anyone help me out? Thanks!!!

Comment: I see in your first version you had `registration.dbo.Enrollment.StudentID`, Can you clarify the database, schema, table and column names?

Comment: for sure, I made a typo earlier. database-registration, schema-dbo, table-enrollment, column-StudentID

Comment: So you should have `use registration` not `use AdventureWorks` and `exec sp_rename 'dbo.enrollment.StudentID', 'Temp', 'COLUMN';` then

Answer (score 3):

Based on the comments this is what you need.

```
USE registration;

EXEC sp_rename 'dbo.enrollment.StudentID', 'Temp', 'COLUMN';
```

Answer (score 0):

the correct call is

```
sp_RENAME 'TableName.[OldColumnName]' , '[NewColumnName]', 'COLUMN'
```

so I think ur code should be

```
USE AdventureWorks
  GO
  EXEC sp_RENAME '[registration].StudentID', 'Temp', 'COLUMN';

  Go
```

Comment: thanks for ur reply AMH!! I tried both '[registration].StudentID', 'Temp', 'COLUMN'; and 'registration.[StudentID]', '[Temp]', 'COLUMN'; but still getting the same error..

Comment: are u sure of the column name

Comment: ok try the accepted answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5330070/problem-with-renaming-a-column-in-sql-server