# How to change column name escaping a character in the name - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'd like to change the name of a column in sql server. This column name is literally `[Responisble Persona]` and I want to change is as `Responsible Person` without the `[]`.

Anybody could help me with this, please?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: You can change the name to "Responsible Person" easily enough, however, because you have a space in the name SQL Server *WILL REQUIRE* the use of square brackets. If you don't want them then you'll need to rename your column to something like `ResponsiblePerson` or `Responsible_Person`.

Comment: You didn't understood my question. The column name contained [] and I wanted to replace them. I could solve it with the answers from this post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5330070/problem-with-renaming-a-column-in-sql-server