# Rename column in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I run

```
EXEC sp_rename 'WSSIESTH.decription', '[DECRP]', 'COLUMN';
```

But sql server makes
[image]

now I want to rename again so I want to run:

```
 EXEC sp_rename 'WSSIESTH.[DECRP]', 'DESCRP', 'COLUMN';
```

but I get the error

```
Msg 15248, Level 11, State 1, Procedure sp_rename, Line 215
Either the parameter @objname is ambiguous or the claimed @objtype (COLUMN) is wrong.
```

What is happend? and How can I rename the column again?

Comment: You need to use `'WSSIESTH."[DECRP]"'` or `'WSSIESTH.[[DECRP]]]'`.

Comment: are you sure you already dont have a column called `DESCRP` in your table ?

Comment: @AaronBertrand wow is that what it is

Comment: @M.Ali Yes the problem is that SQL Server's system procedures have inconsistent handling of quoted identifiers. You can rename to `[some col]` no problem, but you need to escape them when you undo that rename.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Sir whenever you are around I learn something new, Thank you :)

Comment: @AaronBertrand post your answer. Thank you!!!!

Comment: This is duplcate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3091609/how-can-i-solve-either-the-parameter-objname-is-ambiguous-or-the-claimed-objt

Answer (score -1):

Try refreshing the table properties by right clicking on the table name and choosing "Refresh".  Then if your column names look like you expect, you can rename them again.