# Renaming a column of a Table in SQL Server FAILS

Tags: sql, sql-server

I declare a table in a stored procedure and then try to rename one of the columns of the table but it fails:

```
-- create the finaltable
declare @finaltable table(data_date datetime, ind_value float)

Insert into @finaltable (data_date) 
   select distinct l.value_date  
   from #data_table l 
   order by l.value_date

   ---some code here that works

   exec sp_rename '@finaltable.ind_value', 'NewValue', 'COLUMN'     --
```

This part fails

What am I doing wrong?

Error Message:

> Msg 15248, Level 11, State 1, Procedure sp_rename, Line 215
>   Either the parameter @objname is ambiguous or the claimed @objtype (COLUMN) is wrong.

Comment: Hey Matt, edited my question to include the error message.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3091609/how-can-i-solve-either-the-parameter-objname-is-ambiguous-or-the-claimed-objt

Comment: You cannot rename a column in a table variable ...

Comment: It's a table variable - it's entire lifetime lasts just as long as the stored proc executes, and it's invisible to any nested scopes. So the obvious question is, why don't you just create it with the correct column name in the first place? No other piece of code can be depending on the original definition.

Comment: Because I keep adding columns in this table. 
Basically I have a table with a set of data in the form: 
Column1 (Dates), Column2 (Identifiers), Column3 (Values) 
and I want to recreate this table in the form: Column1 (dates), Column2 = Identifier 1, Column3 = Identifier 2 so on, so on..
So I am looping through the individual identifiers and updating the Ind_Value Column and then want to rename 'Ind_Value' with the Identifier Name.

Comment: To expand on what @marc_s has said; because it is a table variable, not a table, you can't rename it. If you read the MSDN documentation on sp_rename (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms188351.aspx), it works on database objects - i.e. things that are in sys.objects. Because a table variable is not persisted, it won't be in sys.objects, so you cannot rename it, or any part of it. Instead, you could try using a temp table, or instead of renaming your column, re-selecting the contents of your table variable into another with the required column names.

Comment: If you are generating your column definitions on the fly, it sounds like a job for dynamic sql: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms188001.aspx

Comment: Thanks Ed, will have a look.

Comment: By all means, what do you expect by putting a parameter into a quoted string ?

Comment: what do you mean? have you looked up how the sp_rename function works?