# Rename SQL Server Index in MS Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to rename index in sales schema by this script:

```
EXEC sp_rename N'sales.table.IX1', N'IX2', N'INDEX';
```

but I get this error:

> Either the parameter @objname is ambiguous or the claimed @objtype (INDEX) is wrong.

How can I solve it?

Comment: SQL is a language for querying databases.  What is your DBMS?

Comment: Are you in the correct database? Are you sure that there is no typo? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190776.aspx

Comment: Try putting square brackets, as mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3091609/how-can-i-solve-either-the-parameter-objname-is-ambiguous-or-the-claimed-objt

Answer (score 3):

Try to remove schema name if you do not have the same table in other schema

```
EXEC sp_rename N'table.IX1', N'IX2', N'INDEX';
```

Comment: @EhsanHP Try EXEC sp_rename N'[table].[IX1]', N'IX2', N'INDEX';

Answer (score 1):

I spent a few more minutes than necessary on this one, because of stupid mistakes:

```
EXEC sp_rename N'SCHEMA.TABLE.OLD_INDEX_NAME', N'NEW_INDEX_NAME', N'index';
```

Note: Don't change `N'index'`, it must stay like this to let the procedure know that you're modifying an index object. Link to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/rename-indexes?view=sql-server-ver15).

Answer (score 0):

I applied this SQL syntax and it works well with me.

```
EXEC sp_rename N'sales.table.IX1', N'sales.table.IX2', N'INDEX';
```

Answer (score 0):

Add schema to table name (brackets are not mandatory)

```
exec sp_rename N'[schema].[table].IX_index', N'IX_index_new', N'INDEX';
```