# Ambigous table's name when rename column in Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a problem related to the name of table. I have a table with name AA.Transaction . I want to rename a column in that table

```
EXEC sp_rename N'AA.[Transaction].Reference', N'CustomerReference', 'COLUMN';
```

And i got an error

> Either the parameter @objname is ambiguous or the claimed @objtype (COLUMN) is wrong.

I realized that the problem is the name of the table (Transaction). If i use another table's name, the script work well.

How i can solve this problem?

Comment: Thoroughly check everything - is the column name correct? Is the table `Transaction` within the `AA` schema or does the table name actually contain a `.` and it's actual name is `AA.Transaction`? It's these sort of checks you need to do and we cannot help, not having access to your database.

Answer (score 1):

Either remove the `[]` or make it like

```
EXEC sp_rename N'[AA].[Transaction].[Reference]', N'CustomerReference', 'COLUMN';
```

Check this post once: [How can i solve "Either the parameter @objname is ambiguous or the claimed @objtype (COLUMN) is wrong."?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3091609/how-can-i-solve-either-the-parameter-objname-is-ambiguous-or-the-claimed-objt)