# Sql Database error showing on my Azure site

Tags: sql-server, azure, database-migration

Below I add an exception that I recieved when I login on my site. The site and database both are hosted on Azure. Probably this is a migration issue. So I deleted the `[dbo].[__MigrationHistory]` table. It's not working when I run my site URL like `arsclub.azurewebsite.net/Account/Login` then it create again `[dbo].[__MigrationHistory]` table and same exception give that below mention. And the again I delete this table `[dbo].[__MigrationHistory]`, and update my `web.config` run locally used the Azure hosted database it works fine and I logged in successfully. What is happening so it not work with this URL `arsclub.azurewebsite.net/Account/Login`, why it giving me exception? Please help

```
[SqlException (0x80131904): Either the parameter @objname is ambiguous or the claimed @objtype (COLUMN) is wrong.]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +212
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +81
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) +629
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) +4411
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite) +952
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry) +304
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() +282
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.<>c.<NonQuery>b__4_0(DbCommand t, DbCommandInterceptionContext`1 c) +12
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch(TTarget target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed) +72
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.NonQuery(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext) +427
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InterceptableDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() +103
   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteSql(MigrationStatement migrationStatement, DbConnection connection, DbTransaction transaction, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext) +109
   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsInternal(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements, DbConnection connection, DbTransaction transaction, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext) +83
   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsWithinTransaction(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements, DbTransaction transaction, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext) +65
   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsWithinNewTransaction(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements, DbConnection connection, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext) +155
   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsInternal(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements, DbConnection connection, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext) +359
   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsInternal(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements, DbConnection connection) +509
   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.<>c__DisplayClass61_0.<ExecuteStatements>b__0() +19
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<Execute>b__0() +10
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Func`1 operation) +189
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Action operation) +78
   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatements(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements, DbTransaction existingTransaction) +211
   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatements(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements) +7
   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteOperations(String migrationId, VersionedModel targetModel, IEnumerable`1 operations, IEnumerable`1 systemOperations, Boolean downgrading, Boolean auto) +938
   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ApplyMigration(DbMigration migration, DbMigration lastMigration) +364
   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId) +133
   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.UpdateInternal(String targetMigration) +451
   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.<>c__DisplayClass42_0.<Update>b__0() +13
   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase) +422
   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String targetMigration) +78
   System.Data.Entity.MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion`2.InitializeDatabase(TContext context) +108
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.<>c__DisplayClass66_0`1.<CreateInitializationAction>b__0() +76
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action action) +60
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformDatabaseInitialization() +357
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.<>c.<InitializeDatabase>b__58_0(InternalContext c) +9
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryAction`1.PerformAction(TInput input) +129
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabaseAction(Action`1 action) +196
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabase() +86
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize() +30
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType) +16
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize() +53
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext() +15
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider() +38
   System.Data.Entity.QueryableExtensions.FirstOrDefaultAsync(IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate, CancellationToken cancellationToken) +138
   System.Data.Entity.QueryableExtensions.FirstOrDefaultAsync(IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate) +145
   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.<GetUserAggregateAsync>d__67.MoveNext() +402
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +102
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +64
   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.CultureAwaiter`1.GetResult() +59
   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.<FindAsync>d__80.MoveNext() +253
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +102
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +64
   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.AsyncHelper.RunSync(Func`1 func) +266
   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManagerExtensions.Find(UserManager`2 manager, String userName, String password) +168
   ClubOps.Login.LogIn(Object sender, EventArgs e) in D:\Workspace\Clubops\MySailingClub\ClubOps\Account\Login.aspx.vb:37
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +109
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +108
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +31
   System.Web.UI.<ProcessRequestMainAsync>d__523.MoveNext() +5661
```

Comment: Have you renamed a column by chance? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3091609/how-can-i-solve-either-the-parameter-objname-is-ambiguous-or-the-claimed-objt

Comment: i did not change the column name

Comment: @DaleK no mistakenly add this tag