Rename column name in SQL Server
The statement: Simple renaming column names were expected.
-- Add ALTER COLUMN commands before renaming to ensure columns are ready for renaming
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[FY_22_23] ALTER COLUMN [CNo] VARCHAR(50);

-- Now rename columns using sp_rename
EXEC sp_rename '[dbo].[FY_22_23].[CNo]', '[CNo#]', 'COLUMN';

returns this error:

Msg 15248, Level 11, State 1, Procedure sp_rename, Line 247 [Batch
Start Line 0] Either the parameter @objname is ambiguous or the
claimed @objtype (COLUMN) is wrong.
Completion time: 2024-09-25T10:38:05.0998645+05:30


I think this is same question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3091609/how-can-i-solve-either-the-parameter-objname-is-ambiguous-or-the-claimed-objt

Or maybe you are simply using wrong (missing) object name ([dbo].[FY_22_23].[CNo])?

FYI, SQL Server 20008 reach end of life over 5 years ago. You urgently need to update to a supported version.

This question is similar to: Rename column SQL Server 2008. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Removing the square brackets from the new name worked for me, e.g.EXEC sp_rename '[dbo].[FY_22_23].[CNo]', 'CNo#', 'COLUMN'; - https://sqlfiddle.com/sql-server/online-compiler?id=899c88a8-699e-4422-982b-b2c57aa14b6b

@GarethD why? Is this the correct syntax or a 'feature' of sqlserver 2008?

Pretty sure '[CNo#]' would have worked in 2008 as well, @GarethD . The only difference is that using '[CNo#]' would mean that the column has the brackets in its name, so to reference the column in the future, the OP would need to use SELECT "[CNo#]" or SELECT [[CNo#]]]. I suspect the problem is that they are trying SELECT CNo# and getting an invalid column name error, which is correct, it's not called CNo#.

@ThomA Yeah, fair point. It does not throw the error in the question even with the square brackets. As the fiddle shows code included does not produce the error in the question where the column definitely exists the logical conclusion is that dbo.FY_22-23 does not contain a column Cno or perhaps it is a view? Agnel, does this code return anything? : SELECT * FROM sys.columns AS c WHERE c.object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[FY_22_23]', 'U') AND c.name = 'Cno';

Cannot reproduce https://dbfiddle.uk/FEYrLvxT it works, although the results are not what you are expecting: it changes the name to [CNo#] not CNo# so you need to escape the brackets as well like SELECT [[CNo#]]] FROM FY_22_23. Please show the actual table definition

Forget the technical here... why would anyone possibly want to rename a column to CNo#? That's probably the worst column name I've ever seen, and I've seen bad ones. Characters in column names are free. They don't cost extra. Name the column something that makes sense. For example, if CNo# is a customer number, name the column CustomerNumber for everyone's sanity.

Just do it. Already tested in my machine.
EXEC sp_rename 'dbo.FY_22_23.CNo', 'CNo#', [COLUMN]


is invalid with that syntax .. https://dbfiddle.uk/YOBZ9Csi and what version of sqlserver is on your machine?

I am using SQL Server 2014 express. In which version you are working? I have also other versions. I can check it.

Please ensure that the object name includes the schema, table, and column names.
EXEC sp_rename 'dbo.MyTable.OldColumnName', 'NewColumnName', 'COLUMN';

CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE (
  empId int,
  name varchar(15),
  dept varchar(10)
);

INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE(empId,name,dept) VALUES (1, 'Clark', 'Sales');
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE(empId,name,dept) VALUES (2, 'Dave', 'Accounting');

-- EXEC sp_RENAME 'TableName.OLDCloumnName','New Column Name','COLUMN'
EXEC sp_RENAME 'EMPLOYEE.Name', 'EMPName' , 'COLUMN'

SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE;
GO

Result :
empId       EMPName         dept    
----------- --------------- ----------
          1 Clark           Sales     
          2 Dave            Accounting 


It would be helpful if you used the column name that he OP has an issue with ie Does this work when attempting to rename CNo as CNo# ?
